# Ensuring www. or https before domain name

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I want to ensure that whenever my website shows up in google search, it shows www.mydomain.com and not mydomain.com. I have set up a web forward from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com in the hope that this will achieve this before I submit my website online.

1. Is there anything else I need to do to achieve www. before my domain name in the search results? I contacted 123 Reg who said the following:

"The www config is done when you set up your website and not by us. If you will create for example a Wordpress website you can set up in it's configuration for the site URL to be www.mydomain.com.  If your website is built with another application you should be able to select from it's configuration but on this you can ask your web developer. As Google Search is a search engine which is not provided by us, you can also check with a SEO expert in how to make your website show the desired URL on a search as well as how you can get the website on the first page of a search."

I do not have a config file, nor know what one is.

2. Also if I wanted a https www. shown on google search results, I assume (after buying an SSL certificate) I would need to set up a forward from mydomain.com to https before www.mydomain.com, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to point your Cname record www.example.com to your A record example.com and your A record point to your server IP address; you can do it by login to your registrar or your hosting if they are all in one service. However, from your question I think your hosting might automatically set it up for you, then you have to set your homepage's URL in your CMS to http://www.example.com, you have to set it up when you access to your site for 1st time or you can change it in setting later on.(if you use WordPress then it is one of CMS).
2. I don't know what your hosting's panel look like, so I will explain it generally. You need you edit your web server(ex: Apache, Nginx) configuration files. Redirect your incoming traffic from server that listen to port 80 to server port 443, and you also need to change your CMS setting to https://www.example.com. You have to do some google for more information about web server's configuration files based on web servers you used if you don't understand what I mean. And you may also need to understand how to setup your ssl.

Note: port 80 is a default port for http, and port 443 is a default port for https.